# how to generalize the XPath in Page Object Class

Tags: c#, xpath

I want to generalize below xpath for checkboxes, how can I do it?

```
[FindWebPageElementBy(ElementFindingStrategy.XPath, "//input[@value='Refrigerators']")]
public WebPageElement Checkbox { get; set; }

[FindWebPageElementBy(ElementFindingStrategy.XPath, "//input[@value='Mobiles']")]
public WebPageElement Checkbox1 { get; set; }

[FindWebPageElementBy(ElementFindingStrategy.XPath, "//input[@value='Appliances']")]
public WebPageElement Checkbox2 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Xpath has an `or` operator which allows you to combine multiple predicates:

```
//input[@value="Appliances" or @value="Mobiles" or @value="Refrigerators"]
```

[image]

Live [xpath tester link](http://granitosaur.us/xpath-tester/?html=PGh0bWw%2BCiAgICA8aW5wdXQgdmFsdWU9IkFwcGxpYW5jZXMiPjwvaW5wdXQ%2BCiAgICA8aW5wdXQgdmFsdWU9Ik1vYmlsZXMiPjwvaW5wdXQ%2BCiAgICA8aW5wdXQgdmFsdWU9IlJlZnJpZ2VyYXRvcnMiPjwvaW5wdXQ%2BCjwvaHRtbD4%3D&xpath=Ly9pbnB1dFtAdmFsdWU9IkFwcGxpYW5jZXMiIG9yIEB2YWx1ZT0iTW9iaWxlcyIgb3IgQHZhbHVlPSJSZWZyaWdlcmF0b3JzIl0%3D#editor)

Comment: How this aaproach will allow me to click each checkbox individually?

Comment: @PurvaKshirsagar the selector will return you an array with 3 element - you can just iterate through them and click each one of them individually. Is that what you meant?